# SQL Update and Join updating wrong records

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I am trying to use an UPDATE statement with a JOIN on SQL Server.

if I run the below SELECT statement it returns 42 rows.

```
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Imported] i 
inner join [DaisyCompare].[dbo].[Baseline] b
on 
b.[CLI]=i.[CLI] AND 
b.[Quantity]=i.[Quantity] AND 
b.[UnitCost]=i.[UnitCost] AND 
b.[TotalCost]=i.[TotalCost] AND 
b.[Description]=i.[Description] 

WHERE b.[CLI]=i.[CLI] AND 
b.[Quantity]=i.[Quantity] AND 
b.[UnitCost]=i.[UnitCost] AND 
b.[TotalCost]=i.[TotalCost] AND 
b.[Description]=i.[Description]
```

However when I use it as a condition within my update statement (below), the query updates 44 records.

```
update [DaisyCompare].[dbo].[Baseline]

set Disposition = ('Match')

where exists (
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Imported] i 
inner join [DaisyCompare].[dbo].[Baseline] b

on 
b.[CLI]=i.[CLI] AND 
b.[Quantity]=i.[Quantity] AND 
b.[UnitCost]=i.[UnitCost] AND 
b.[TotalCost]=i.[TotalCost] AND 
b.[Description]=i.[Description] 

WHERE b.[CLI]=i.[CLI] AND 
b.[Quantity]=i.[Quantity] AND 
b.[UnitCost]=i.[UnitCost] AND 
b.[TotalCost]=i.[TotalCost] AND 
b.[Description]=i.[Description] )
```

Presumably my syntax is wrong, but I am not sure where.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Because your EXISTS logic is checking for the existence of rows and there is no correlation. I would get rid of the EXISTS and just use a join. Also, what is the point of the where clause here? It is already handled in the join predicates.

Answer (score 0):

you can use an alias to choose which of the join tables to update

```
UPDATE b
SET Disposition = 'Match'
FROM [dbo].[Imported] i 
inner join [DaisyCompare].[dbo].[Baseline] b
on 
b.[CLI]=i.[CLI] AND 
b.[Quantity]=i.[Quantity] AND 
b.[UnitCost]=i.[UnitCost] AND 
b.[TotalCost]=i.[TotalCost] AND 
b.[Description]=i.[Description]
```

Comment: I would get rid of the where clause. It is redundant since all those criteria are matched in the inner join already.

Comment: Fair point, I didn't get to the bottom and copy pasted, servers me right for being lazy

Answer (score 0):

You can use normal update syntax with a join, and you only need the join predicates, the where clause is redundant:

```
UPDATE b
SET Disposition = 'Match'
FROM [dbo].[Imported] i 
INNER JOIN [DaisyCompare].[dbo].[Baseline] b
ON
b.[CLI]=i.[CLI] AND 
b.[Quantity]=i.[Quantity] AND 
b.[UnitCost]=i.[UnitCost] AND 
b.[TotalCost]=i.[TotalCost] AND 
b.[Description]=i.[Description]
```

Answer (score 0):

The "exists" is definitely the issue.  You could use an IN and reference whatever the Primary Key is.

```
update [DaisyCompare].[dbo].[Baseline]

set Disposition = ('Match')

where [DaisyCompare].[dbo].[Baseline].[PrimaryID] IN
 (
SELECT [b.PrimaryID] FROM [dbo].[Imported] i 
inner join [DaisyCompare].[dbo].[Baseline] b

on 
b.[CLI]=i.[CLI] AND 
b.[Quantity]=i.[Quantity] AND 
b.[UnitCost]=i.[UnitCost] AND 
b.[TotalCost]=i.[TotalCost] AND 
b.[Description]=i.[Description] 

WHERE b.[CLI]=i.[CLI] AND 
b.[Quantity]=i.[Quantity] AND 
b.[UnitCost]=i.[UnitCost] AND 
b.[TotalCost]=i.[TotalCost] AND 
b.[Description]=i.[Description] )
```